# How to merge datarows and calculate sum using C#/Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have input datatable:

```
Id  Rating  Col1 Col2
2000    A   10   20
2000    A   10   20
2000    A+  5    15
2000    A+  5    15
4000    A   10   20
4000    A   10   20
4000    A+  5    15
4000    A+  5    15
```

**ExpectedOutPut**

I want to merge datarows on the basis of a particular Id and for a particular rating. The ratings can vary as per the Id. **I have more than 100 columns in real datatable and there also I just want to calculate the sum.**

```
Id  Rating  Col1    Col2
2000    A   20     40
2000    A+  10     30
4000    A   20     40
4000    A+  10     30
```

First I tried using these methods. But was not able to complete them:

```
var Ids = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(row => row.Field<int>("Id")).Distinct();

            foreach (var id in Ids)
            {
                //Get Ratings in the account
                var ratings = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(row => row.Field<int>("Id") == id).Select(row => row.Field<string>("Rating")).Distinct();

                foreach (var rating in ratings)
                {

                }
            }


var groups = dt.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(row => new { Column1 = row.Field<string>("Id"), Column2 = row.Field<string>("Rating") });
            .Select(group => new
             {
                 Column1 = group.Key.Column1,
                 Column2 = group.Key.Column2,
                 Count = group.Count()
             });
```

How can I fulfill this task?

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need:

```
var groups =
    dt
        .AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(
            row => new
            {
                Id = row.Field<string>("Id"),
                Rating = row.Field<string>("Rating")
            },
            row => new
            {
                Col1 = row.Field<int>("Col1"),
                Col2 = row.Field<int>("Col2")
            })
        .Select(group => new
        {
            group.Key.Id,
            group.Key.Rating,
            Col1 = group.Sum(x => x.Col1),
            Col2 = group.Sum(x => x.Col2),
        });
```

Comment: I have 100 columns in my code datatable. I will have to manually map them? @Enigmativity

Comment: It is also giving invalid cast error while doing Col1 = row.Field<int>("Col1")

Comment: @ShishankJain - Your question showed two columns. If there are more you should show that in your question. You should also provide us with the C# code that loads sample data into a `DataTable`. Then we can write code we can test. Could you do that please?